# apache 2 and flask, reportlab registerFont "TTFError: Can't open file ..." but works on dev server

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, reportlab

am new to python and i am trying to get flask micro-framework to work with apache. I am using the wsgi setup instructions as described in the following article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

unfortunately, although the application works fine, when trying to produce a pdf using reportlab I am getting the following error (extract from apache logs)

```
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error] ERROR:flaskapp:Exception on /print/0 [GET]
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/var/www/flaskapp/flaskapp/__init__.py", line 124, in print_rep
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     registerFont(TTFont('DroidSans', 'DroidSans.ttf'))
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 1009, in __init__
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     self.face = TTFontFace(filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 915, in __init__
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     TTFontFile.__init__(self, filename, validate=validate, subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 412, in __init__
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     TTFontParser.__init__(self, file, validate=validate,subfontIndex=subfontIndex)
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 189, in __init__
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     self.readFile(file)
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 263, in readFile
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     self.filename, f = TTFOpenFile(f)
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/ttfonts.py", line 175, in TTFOpenFile
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error]     raise TTFError('Can\\'t open file "%s"' % fn)
[Thu Jan 09 22:47:44 2014] [error] TTFError: Can't open file "DroidSans.ttf"
```

it looks like that the registerFont can't access the font.

running it in the development server, it works fine.

I tried several locations, even putting the font in a font folder within the reportlab folder but still nothing. 
looked in this article that suggests fast_cgi (for Django) but I am not sure if this will solve my problem.

[python reportlab - registerFont - django - font not available after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628377/python-reportlab-registerfont-django-font-not-available-after-some-time)

any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is your exact code? Is the filename a relative path?

Comment: Specifically, the current working directory under Apache/mod_wsgi will not by default be where your application is, so you cannot use relative path names.

Comment: I thought it was relative but it is absolute paths where fonts are searched in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

font files must be in paths declared in reportlab.rl_config.TTFSearchpath (search path list)

Try to output list content.

And, no, switching to fast_cgi with Django won't make you understand what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I added the path to TTFSearchPath dynamicly and now works. I was just reffering to Django because it works. (I used Django / reportlab in an other project with no issues.)